# vb.net Exclude extension from "GetFiles"

Tags: vb.net, io, extension-methods, getfiles

I'm currently adding all found documents in a directory and sub-directory into a listbox.
This works perfectly, for my need, but i'm getting too much unwanted files.

The code for adding the files into my listbox:

```
ES_MAIN_SPECIFICATIONS_LIST.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(oFolder, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

The * makes that all files are **included** but how can I **exclude** a certain extention?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to then loop through again, removing those with the extensions you don't want. You can also use LINQ (`.Where(...)`) to do the same thing inline:

```
ES_MAIN_SPECIFICATIONS_LIST.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(oFolder, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(p) Not IO.Path.GetExtension(p).Equals("excludeMe"))
```

Comment: @JefE did my answer help? If so, can you mark it as the answer (green tick)?